# Firebase in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to iOS development also using Firebase. I want to know that if it's advisable to create sub collections under my users collection in my Firestore database so that each user once they have authenticated they will have access to their own data? Or shall i create new collections and reference the users ids once they authenticated with my login.

Reason i ask because there's multiple ways of using firebase but some ways aren't efficient and i want to know, what is recommended>

Comment: Since Firestore is a NoSQL, document-oriented database, meaning that it is not a relational database, the first approach you mention is way better than the second approach. For the second one, basically you are treating document-oriented database like a relational one. You can read some official documentations to see what options do you have: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/concepts/structure-data and https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model

Comment: alright thank you.

Comment: Also  i want to ask, if i use sub collections how do i ensure for each user stored in my whole users collection they can't access another users data?

Comment: The Firebase documentation deals specifically with how to do this using rules: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication

Comment: I suggest that creating sub collections may not be a good approach. While @BurakAkkaş comment is valid, without understanding the entire use case, it would be difficult to make an accurate suggestion; your Firebase Structure is dependent on what queries you want to run. There are only some cases where a users data is *only* a users data that's never shared. Nesting collections makes those queries difficult to craft and not easily scalable. So, this ends up being an opinion type question which is unanswerable. Provide query details and a proposed structure and we'll take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned by @BurakAkkaş, @jnpdx and @Jay, Firestore is a NoSQL, document-oriented database. With that said, creating sub collections for a `users` collection in a Firestore DB so that each user has access to their own data once authenticated may be (and may not be) a better approach than creating new collections and reference the users IDs once they authenticated with your login.

[Structuring Data](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/concepts/structure-data) and [Cloud Firestore Data model](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model) can help to understand how to structure your DB.

If you want to use sub collections and ensure that users can't access other users data, please refer to the [Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication) article.

Without understanding the entire use case, it's difficult to make an accurate suggestion; your Firebase Structure is dependent on what queries you want to run. There are only some cases where a users data is only a users data that's never shared. Nesting collections makes those queries difficult to craft and not easily scalable.

You can provide your query details and a proposed structure to get further community support.